# How to print a dictionary without any special characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
myDict = {"word" : [10],
          "other word" : [16]}
```

I was wondering how I would be able to print this out in this format:

```
word 10
other word 16
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the key/value pairs in the dict and print them line by line is a solid starting point for the majority of cases:

```
for key, value in myDict.items():
    print(key, *value, sep = " ")
```

You need to use the `*` or destructuring operator because your value is a `list`.

For a more in-depth examination of several examples, the following is an excellent example from the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques

Comment: `print(key,value)` adds a space implicitly :)

Comment: @FabioCraigWimmerFlorey Sure I just thought it would be good in case he would like to change the print format but I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: In this case, if the value is an array, you may use ```*```. Otherwise, the brackets will be displayed.  To get rid of them```print(key, *value)```. However this works only if ```value``` is an iterator. (In the OP example, it's a list, then i should work)

Comment: Alternatively, something more like `' '.join(map(str, value))`

Comment: @Sayse &Metapod I have edited the answer accordingly you are right. Premtheus thanks for this one it works too, you should maybe add it as an answer it could help some folks out there.

Comment: Thanks so much! It turns out that the code I had before was pretty much exactly what I needed but I just had to add * to the front of the value.